# Why the div is not maintained their aspect ratio while displaying image?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, web-deployment

This is html code snippet:

```js
    my_button.onclick = () => {
        image_holder_div.classList.remove('display_none_class');
        let imgTag = `<img id="nnn" src="${fileURL}" class="mx-auto d-block" alt="..."></img>`;
        image_holder_div.innerHTML = imgTag;
    }
```

```css
    .container-fluid{
        max-width: 650px;
        width: 95%;
        padding: 30px;
        background-color: rgb(250, 252, 253);
        border-radius: 4px;
        border: 1px solid #dfe1e5;
        /* box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px; */

        position: relative;
    }

    .first{
        height: 400px;
        border: 2px dashed #8b8e96;
        background-color: #fffce5;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        flex-direction: column;
        margin: 10px auto;
    }

    .image_holder_div{
        height: 400px;
        width: 100%;
        border: 2px dashed #8b8e96;
        background-color: #b4a429;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        flex-direction: column;
        margin: 10px auto;
        position: absolute;
        top: 30px;
    }
```

```html
       <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="first">
            </div>

            <div class="image_holder_div display_none_class">
            </div>
        </div>
```

When I click on my_button to display image, the image_holder_div not maintained aspect ratio while displaying image. It's showing like this I upload the image here
[image_holder_div](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wyWyf.png)
Can anyone please tell me why it's happening and how can I fix this issue...

Comment: It will not maintain aspect if height is fixed and the width  is %, try setting image to a background-image of fixed width and height div, it should work that way.

Answer (score 0):

Explanation of the cause:
It's totally clear from the code, that you have set the width of `image_holder-div` to 100% of its parent container. Since its parent element is `.container-fluid`, it would attain its width. It is seen that you have added `padding: 30px` in `.container-fluid`, hence, you see a space of 30 pixels between the parent and image holder div.

Solution:
You can add the following styling on the `image_holder_div`:
`width: calc(100% - 60px);`
Adding this line would use some CSS calculations and set the height of the div equal to 100% of the parent element minus 60px, i.e. 30px from left and right both. (Don't forget to add space before and after the minus sign)
For more about the `calc()` function:
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/func_calc.asp